# To throw an error if a string contains a specific character

Tags: javascript, regex, angular

I am new to regex and I just wanted to know what can be a possible regex to check if my string contains either of the following characters: o, q, i, O, Q, I.

I am currently doing this using the following approach:

```
const notAllowedCharacters = ['Q' , 'q' , 'O' , 'o', 'I' , 'i'];
const nameValue = this.form.get('nameValue').value.split('');
nameValue.forEach(value => {
  if(notAllowedCharacters.indexOf(value) > -1) {
   this.isValidName = false;
  }
})
```

Thanks.

Comment: `nameValue.match(/[oqiOQI]/).length>0`

Comment: Play around on regex101.com. This helped me understand regex better.

Comment: @Floris Thanks, will check.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using reactive forms in Angular, you may use a "pattern"  in *Validators.pattern* in your form control:

```
Validators.pattern("[^oOqQiI]+")
```

Or,

```
Validators.pattern(/^[^oqi]+$/i)
```

`/^[^oqi]+$/i` expression matches a whole string that consists of any one or more characters that are not `o`, `q` and `i` (`i` is the case insensitive flag).

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/Yrhtom/1).

Comment: Thank you :). Yes, this should work. I don't know how I missed this.

Comment: @AkhileshOjha Please  accept the an answer that works best for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple regex:

```
this.isValidName = !/[oqi]/i.test(this.form.get('nameValue').value);
```

Basically what this does it do a case insensitive regex test on the string.

[example](https://regexr.com/56nlk)

Comment: `g` flag doesn't look necessary, stopping on first occurrence  should be sufficient.

Comment: @PJProudhon absolutely right, force of habit to always add `g` :) would be interesting to see if there is any execution time difference, but I guess this is already optimized by returning after the first find

Comment: I'd be curious too :)

Comment: @PJProudhon your curiosity has been satisfied: [jsperf](https://jsperf.com/regex-global-test-vs-non-global/1) without `g` it's faster! Obviously not noticeable in normal code, but nice to know